# Best options for image resizing

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have to resize images exceeding a max size. Different methods I tried so far are not good enough:

1. `System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImage` generates very poor quality images in general.
2. Playing with options like this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx) I can generate better images in quality but heavier than the original one.

Probably the second option (or something similar) is the best option and I would need to resize using the proper options.

Any advice?

**EDIT**
My option 2 was generating heavier images for some specific pictures. In general is working as expected so I'd say this is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public Bitmap Resize(Bitmap originalImage, int newWidth)
{
    int newHeight = (int)Math.Round(originalImage.Height * (decimal)newWidth / originalImage.Width, 0);
    var destination = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Thanks OrbMan. Just tested it. Unfortunately I'm having the same issue as my option 2. Reduced images are heavier than original:-(

Comment: What format are they being retrieved as/saved in? If you're saving the thumbnail as a bitmap I wouldn't be surprised if they were large. Make sure you're using jpeg or png or some other compressed format.

Comment: @Sean: Same format I retrieve same format I save. I'm processing image of any kind.

Comment: @OrbMan: It was generating heavier images for some specific pictures. In general is working as expected.

Comment: @Claudio, I would suggest using the WPF libs, as mentioned in my answer. It's the future :)

Comment: @OrbMan: forget about it :-), as I said, I'm having issues for some very specific images. Works perfect for the most of them. @Mikael: I will take into account your advice too. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with using the WPF libs instead of the GDI+ libs. The WPF libs perform faster and I think they yield better results compared to the GDI+ libs.

Check out these excellent posts from Bertrand Le Roy.

- [Resizing images from the server using WPF/WIC instead of GDI+](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/01/21/server-side-resizing-with-wpf-now-with-jpg.aspx)
- [Server-side resizing with WPF: now with JPG](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/01/21/server-side-resizing-with-wpf-now-with-jpg.aspx)
- [The fastest way to resize images from ASP.NET. And it’s (more) supported-ish](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/05/03/the-fastest-way-to-resize-images-from-asp-net-and-it-s-more-supported-ish.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `Bitmap` object, then using the `Graphics` object, re-draw the old image into the new image's buffer at the increased/decreased size based on the resize engine you want.

```
// inImage is your original
Bitmap outImage = new Bitmap(newWid, newHei);

Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(outImage);
gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

gfx.DrawImage(inImage,
   new Rectangle(0, 0, newWid, new Hei),
   new Rectangle(0, 0, inImage.Width, inImage.Height),
   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: Thanks Aren. This is very similar to the code posted by OrbMan and my issue with this is that generates heavier images than the original

Comment: That's because the default format is probably BMP format. You can "save" it to a memory stream with in ImageFormatter and use png/jpg to compress the image data.